# How do I remove multiple hyperlinks in Microsoft Office Word easily?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

As the question reads, I want to be able to select a block of text and remove all the hyperlinks in it at once.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a hot-key for removing hyperlinks in a text selection in Microsoft Office, since Office 97.

1. Select the block of text.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>.
   Note: depending on your keyboard layout/configuration,
   you may also need to hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> in order to get <kbd>F9</kbd> to work.

Comment: Just a warning, this will unlink every type of field that happens to be in the selection, not just hyperlinks.

Comment: From user [MontereyDean](http://superuser.com/users/678605/montereydean): It took me forever to figure out why "CTRL + SHIFT + F9" wasn't working. On my computer, it's "CTRL + Fn + SHIFT + F9."

Comment: @fixer1234 No, it's not. The key combination being sent to Word is still just what is given in my answer. It just so happens that if you look at your F9 key, there will be some other symbol there, and so for example what you were actually pressing without the `Fn` key was something like `Ctrl+Shift+Toggle Wi-Fi`